# Why is tanh a "smoothly" differentiable function?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, math, activation-functions, tanh

The sigmoid, tanh, and ReLU are popular and useful activation functions in the literature.

The following excerpt taken from p4 of [Neural Networks and Neural Language Models](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/7.pdf) says that `tanh` has a couple of interesting properties.

> For example, the tanh function has the nice properties of being
> **smoothly differentiable** and mapping outlier values toward the mean.

A function is said to be differentiable if it is differentiable at every point in the domain of function. The domain of `tanh` is $\mathbb{R}$ and $ \dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$.

But what is meant by "**smoothly** differentiable" in the case of `tanh` activation function?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty subjective description. I would argue sigmoid is also smoothly differentiable because the gradient function is predictable and symmetric. It could maybe be referring to how the tanh derivative exists in one of 3 states: Essentially stationary, linear, or a transition between the two.

Comment: In math, as far as I know, "smooth" often refers to the fact that the function can be differentiated multiple times. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness).  To be honest, I never really thought about the properties of the hyperbolic tangent, so I don't know if the author of that excerpt is referring to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [smooth function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothFunction.html) is usually defined to be a function that is $n$-times *continuously differentiable*, which means that $f$, $f'$, $\dots$, $f^{(n - 1)}$ are all differentiable and $f^{(n)}$ is continuous. Such functions are also called $C^n$ functions.

It can be a bit of a vague term; some people might even stretch the definition and say any continuous function is smooth (though I'd be a little surprised if I saw that in use, personally). Other people write smooth to mean *infinitely differentiable*: for example $f(x) = e^x$ can be differentiated as many times as you like.

I guess what the author is trying to point out is that the ReLU rectifier function isn't differentiable. Even if you use the "trick"<sup>1</sup> of treating ReLU as differentiable everywhere, you would still get a derivative that is **discontinuous**:

$$\mathrm{ReLU}'(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \ge 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

So, it's fair to say that ReLU isn't smooth in the same sense of the $\tanh$ function, which has a continuous derivative (and, in fact, you could carry on and consider the higher derivatives).

---

<sup>1</sup> If this doesn't sound familiar, see p. 188 of [Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) by Bengio et al. We can get around the fact that ReLU functions aren't differentiable at zero by just pretending it has a well-defined derivative of zero or one. A little dishonest, perhaps, but it works very well.