# What are the necessary mathematical properties to be a loss function in gradient based optimizations?

Tags: deep-learning, objective-functions, math, optimization, gradient-descent

Loss functions are used in training neural networks.

I am interested in knowing the mathematical properties that are necessary for a loss function to **participate in gradient descent optimization**.

I know some *possible* candidates that may decide whether a function can be a loss function or not. They include

1. Continuous at every point in $\mathbb{R}$
2. Differentiable at every point in $\mathbb{R}$

But, I am not sure whether these two properties are necessary for a function to become a loss function.

Are these two properties **necessary**?  Are there any **other mathematical properties that are necessary** for a function to become a loss function to participate in gradient descent optimization?

Note that this question is not asking for recommended properties for a loss function. Asking only the mandatory properties in a given context.

Answer (score 3):

**Summary:** the loss needs to be differentiable, with some caveats.

---

I will introduce some notation, which I hope is clear: if not I am happy to clarify.

Consider a neural network with parameters $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$, which is usually a vector of weights and biases. The gradient descent algorithm seeks to find parameters $\theta_\mathrm{min}$ which minimise the loss
function
$$\mathcal{L} \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}.$$

---

If this seems abstract, suppose $f(x; \theta)$ is the neural network and $S = \{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i = 1}^n$ is the training set. In binary classification we could have the loss function

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{1} \{f(x_i; \theta) \ne y_i\} $$
where $\mathbb{1}$ is the indicator function which is $1$ if the condition is satisfied and zero otherwise. I consider the loss function to be a function of
the *parameters* and not the data, which is fixed.

---

Gradient descent is performed by the update rule
$$ \theta_n \leftarrow \theta_{n - 1} - \gamma \nabla \mathcal{L}(\theta_{n - 1}),$$
yielding new parameters $\theta_n$ which should give a smaller loss $\mathcal{L}(\theta_n)$. The quantity $\gamma$ is the familiar *learning rate*.

The gradient descent rule requires the *gradient* $\nabla \mathcal{L}(\theta_{n - 1})$ to be defined, so the loss function must be differentiable. In most texts on calculus or mathematical analysis you'll find the result that if a function is
differentiable at a point $x$, it is also continuous at $x$. Obviously there is no
hope that we could perform this procedure without knowing the gradient!

In principle, differentiability is sufficient to run gradient descent. That said, unless $\mathcal{L}$ is convex, gradient descent offers no guarantees of convergence to a global minimiser. In practice, neural network loss functions are rarely convex
anyway.

I have omitted discussion on stochastic gradient descent, but it does not change the requirements for the loss function. There are alternative techniques such as the [proximal gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_method) for non-differentiable functions.

An unfortunate technicality I have to mention is
that, strictly speaking, if you use the $\mathrm{ReLU}$ activation function, the
neural network function $f$ becomes non-differentiable. I discuss this further in [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28588/44413). In practice we can assign
a value and "pretend" $\mathrm{ReLU}$ is differentiable everywhere.