# Is my understanding on "smooth approximation" correct?

Tags: comparison, terminology, definitions, activation-functions

Consider the [following details](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softplus.html) regarding Softplus activation function

> $$\text{Softplus}(x) = \dfrac{\log(1+e^{\beta x})}{\beta}$$
>
> SoftPlus is a **smooth approximation** to the ReLU function and can be
> used to constrain the output of a machine to always be positive.

It says that Softplus is a smooth approximation to the ReLU function. Let us consider the analytical form and plot of the RELU function.

$$\text{ReLU}(x)=(x)^+=\max(0,x)$$

[image]

The plot of Softplus function is

[image]

If we observe both plots, we can see the Softplus is almost similar to ReLU. There is a property for Softplus that ReLU does not have. [ReLU is not differentiable at zero and the derivative of ReLU is also not continuous](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28588/18758).

If we observe the behavior of Softplus, it is $n-$times continuously differentiable and hence a smooth function.

Since Softplus is both a smooth function and approximates ReLU, it is considered as a smooth approximation of ReLU.

Is my interpretation correct? if no, then what is meant by "smooth approximation" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is definitely correct. As you correctly pointed out, the derivative of `softplus` is continuous and $n$-times differentiable, that makes the function smooth, which is not the case for `ReLU`.

What is quite interesting here is *why* `softplus` can be called an approximation to `ReLU`.

If we break down the definition of `softplus`, we note that the parameter $\beta$ controls the *smoothness* of the function. In fact, we can define a *temperature* $T = \frac{1}{\beta}$ (much like the *softmax* function).
Let's denote with $f_T$ a softplus function with temperature $T$. We can easily see that as $T \rightarrow 0$ (or equivalently $\beta \rightarrow \infty$), $f_T(x) \rightarrow \max(0, x)$. In fact, let's compute the limit of the softplus for all $x > 0$:

$\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\beta} ln(1 + e^{\beta x})$

Rewrite $ln(1+e^{\beta x})$ as $ln(e^{-\beta x} + 1) +ln(e^{\beta x})$ we get:

$\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\beta}[ln(e^{-\beta x} + 1) +ln(e^{\beta x})] 
= \\ = 
\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\beta}[ln(0 + 1) + ln(e^{\beta x})]
= \\ = 
\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\beta}[0 + ln(e^{\beta x})] 
= \\ = 
\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\beta}\beta x = \\ = x$

Computing the limit for $x \leq 0 $ is straightforward and the result is $0$.
So we see that for high value of $\beta$ (or low value of $T$), the softplus is actually the $\max(0, x)$ function!

Therefore, softplus is a *family* of functions $f_T$ which approximate ReLU with high precision as $T$ gets to 0 (less smoothness), and low precision with high $T$ (more smoothness).

Among all, we usually use softplus with $beta = 1$ (i.e, $f_1$), and this is why we call it a *smooth approximation* of the ReLU. Because $f_1(x)$ is smooth ($T=1$) and approximates $f_\infty(x) = \max(0, x) = \text{ReLU}(x)$.

Hope this was useful.